# An orientable surface that cannot be embedded into $\Bbb R^3$?

Tags: manifolds, surfaces, orientation, compact-manifolds, non-orientable-surfaces

By [Whitney's embedding theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitney_embedding_theorem), every 2-dimensional manifold (aka. a surface) can be embedded into $\Bbb R^4$.

Now, the Wikipedia page on that theorem states [in this paragraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitney_embedding_theorem#Restrictions_on_manifolds) that we can even embedd into $\Bbb R^3$ if the surface is

- compact and orientable, or
- compact and with non-empty boundary.

This seems to suggest that there is an *orientable* but *non-compact* surface that does not embedd into $\Bbb R^3$. Is this true?

Comment: The question got an answer [over here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/358326/156219).